# How To Move Download of Images to Background Thread To Smooth UI?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading, cocoa-touch

I have this method and I was advised to do the download of images on the background thread.  Can anyone help me with this?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSURL *myURL=[NSURL URLWithString:[self.picturesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]; 
    NSData *myData1 = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:myURL];
    UIImage *myImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:myData1]; 

    cell.imageView.image = myImage;

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting aside the fact that the code shown couldn't possibly work by itself... what you want to do is pretty easy. Your cell could be a custom UITableCell in which you define a method that does your download in the background. In cellForRowAtIndexPath:, you'd call that method, e.g. `[cell loadImageInBackground:myURL]`. The clever part is that the cell, of course, knows what is in it, i.e. the UIImageView you want to setup. So the background load, when it completes, can just set the image, and your table remains responsive.

Comment: Thanks, ya I just posted the code related to downloading the images, not all of it.  But i'd rather keep the code in this method instead of making it apart of the custom cell's class if possible.

Comment: You can do that, too. :-) It won't be as clean (that's a matter of opinion), but it'll work. You can create a method that you invoke using something like `performSelectorInBackground` and pass to it an object with context, or the cell (having set the URL you want to load), or the indexPath, or something so your background method knows what to do and where to display the result.

Comment: The obvious disadvantage of using a background thread for each download is that it's hard to cancel running downloads. So if the user is scrolling quickly, you could very well run out of memory. A better approach would be to use `NSURLConnection` which can use the main thread (for delegate callbacks) without blocking while it's loading. Of course you could also run an `NSURLConnection` on a background thread (with its own runloop) but it's usually not worth the effort.

Comment: Right, thats what I had in mind.  Do you have any code snippet you could provide to get me started?  Within my cellForRowAtIndex method I would call another method that loads the images in the background, then passes them back into the cellForRowAtIndex?

Comment: @omz That's a good point, and one I faced when I had to implement this myself. (I forgot about that nuance. :-) My solution was to define a custom cell, and each cell had a background thread. But to address the issue of cell re-use before an image download completed because the user was fast-scrolling the list, I implemented the method `prepareForReuse` in my cell class. There I could detect easily if the cell's background thread was running, and cancel it! It works pretty well, actually.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a UIImageView that downloads asynchronously. Check this one out:
http://iphone-dev-tips.alterplay.com/2009/10/asynchronous-uiimage.html

You should create a UITableViewCell subclass and add an AsynchronousImageView to it and then do [cell.asyncImageView loadImageFromURLString:[self.picturesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]].